# How to set the browser window title in a qooxdoo desktop application?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I can't find any information in the docs. It defaults to the name of the application, but how to change the title?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that is thats plain DOM API. You can just set the title property of the document like

```
document.title = "new title";
```

You can find more details on the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.title

Comment: This works, but: when you load the page, the title is set to the application name for a moment, and then changes to the "new title". This is most likely because in build/index.html the <title> tag is still set to the application name. I can't change it there, because it is regenerated.

Comment: So, while the page is loading, the title is shown from the index.html. When it is loaded, it is changed as needed. Maybe it is possible to change it in the html?

Comment: You can also change it in the index.html file. It's in the head tag. As the index is not touched by the generator, that should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, this is it. I saw that build/index.html is regenerated, but it uses the source/index.html Please, post this as an answer or update the current answer, so I can accept it for future novices :)